# removeClass in not working

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I want to `removeClass` when `scrolltop` is more then 200px.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(scroll);
  if (scroll >= 100 || scroll <= 200) {
    $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
  } else {
    $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
  }
});
```

```css
.clearHeader {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.66);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your need to use `&&` instead of `||`

```
if(scroll >= 100 && scroll <= 200)
    $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
}
else{
    $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
}
```

Which can also be achieved using `toogleClass()`

```
$(".clearHeader").toggleClass("darkHeader", scroll >= 100 && scroll <= 200);
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".clearHeader").toggleClass("darkHeader", scroll >= 100 && scroll <= 200);
});
```

```css
.clearHeader {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.66);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1- please always use toggleClass() instead of removing and adding... It takes less memory + less code...
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

2- If you want to do something in a specific condition, always use "&&".. This shows how it work:
&&
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_comparison_and